# Identity including derivative of polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, derivatives

Let $f(x)=(x-a_{1})(x-a_{2})...(x-a_{n})$, where $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ are pairwise distinct and neither of them is zero. Prove that

$ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{a_{j}^{n-1}}{f'(a_{j})}=1$

I've proved that using Cauchy residue theorem, but I'm looking for solution requiring less knowledge.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the same rational function that you used, do partial fraction decomposition. The residue theorem can be replaced by the uniqueness of the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: You can just use the partial fraction expansion of $x^{n-1}/f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac {a_j^{n-1}}{f'(a_j)(x-a_j)} $ and then multiply by $f(x) $ and compare coefficients of $x^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be easily shown with *[Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Definition)*. Since $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(x-a_i\right)$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
f^{\prime}(x)&=\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{{i=1}\atop{i\ne j}}^n\left(x-a_i\right)
\qquad\quad f^{\prime}(a_k)=\prod_{{i=1}\atop{i\ne k}}\left(a_k-a_i\right)\quad 1\leq k\leq n
\end{align*}
and the claim can be written as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{{i=1}\atop{i\ne j}}^n\frac{a_j}{a_j-a_i}=1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We consider the Lagrange polynomial $L(x)$
> \begin{align*}
> L(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{{i=1}\atop{i\ne j}}^n\frac{a_j-x}{a_j-a_i}
> \qquad\text{with}\qquad
> L(a_k)=1\quad 1\leq k\leq n
> \end{align*}
> Since $L(x)-1$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ with $n$ zeros $a_k,1\leq k\leq n$ it follows
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{L(x)-1=0}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{L(0)=\sum_{j=1}^n\prod_{{i=1}\atop{i\ne j}}^n\frac{a_j}{a_j-a_i}=1}
> \end{align*}
> follows.

Answer (score 0):

A partial fractions argument similar to the one described in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891102/154826 would go as follows.

First, we have that $f'(a_j) = \prod_{i \neq j}(a_j - a_i)$, so that we're dealing with the quantity
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_j^{n-1}}{f'(a_j)}
= \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_j^{n-1}}{\prod_{i\neq j}(a_j - a_i)}.
\end{align*}

Now, consider the rational functionwith corresponding partial fraction decomposition
\begin{equation}
R(x)
= \frac{x^{n-1}}{\prod_{i=1}^n(x - a_i)}
= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i}{x - a_i},\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
b_j
= \lim_{x \rightarrow a_j}(x - a_j)R(x)
= \frac{a_j^{n-1}}{\prod_{i\neq j}(a_j - a_i)}.
\end{align*}

But now, multiplying both sides of (1) by $x$, we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^n}{\prod_{j=1}^n (x - a_j)}
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{x}{x - a_j} b_j.
\end{align*}

Taking $x\rightarrow \infty$ on both sides then yields
\begin{align*}
1
= \sum_{j=1}^n b_j
= \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_j^{n-1}}{\prod_{i\neq j}(a_j - a_i)}.
\end{align*}